# Any delphi component for digital signing documents?

Tags: delphi, digital-signature

I'm looking for a good standard based component for digitally sign documents with x509 certificates. I can't see no one native component for this. Only Activex components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OpenSSL for that.

take a look here: [delphiopenssl](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/RSAMD5sig.html)

Comment: for missing procedures please look for AskPassphrase.html,OpenSSLUtils.pas

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing it yourself is that you don't have a third party being an independent verification of the validity of the certificate.

It's a trust thing, and that's why companies like VeriSign and Comodo make the big bucks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Secure Black Box from Eldos](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) which I have used in my apps to "sign" files.